# How do I make neat fluid past max width

Tags: css, fluid-layout, bourbon, neat

I don't feel that neat's grid is truly fluid. A fluid grid would scale well all the way from mobile to a large tv screen such as `1920x1080`. However the way that neat and bitters end up working creates a `$max-width` variable which is default set at 1088. Even if you change this however there is a size that the website will stop being fluid, the max-size. I feel a fluid layout would constantly grow and shrink no matter the size of the screen.

Currently my way around this is by using `fill-parent`

```
.outer-container {
  @include fill-parent;
}
```

This works but it feels hacky, is there no way using neat to properly create a fully fluid grid? Setting max-width has it's limit.

Comment: Maybe you can try changing the `$max-width` value to `100%` in the settings of neat.

If that doesn't work you can always set different breackpoints from mobile to large screen.

Comment: The 100% didn't work unfortunately and how would you set a breakpoint for making the max-width larger when the screen is bigger then its original max width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `outer-container` on an element that's supposed to fill the entire viewport. The only thing that mixin does is centering an element, clearing its floats and giving it a max-width.

In CSS, element are `width: 100%` by default, so there is no need to specify anything if that's the expected result.

The 'fluid' part of Neat refers to the fact that it does't use fixed widths, but percentages.